# Can I specify a class for value rev?

Tags: css

```
<a href="img1.jpg" rel="zoom-id:bike" rev="img1.jpg"> <img src="" class="img-thumb"/></a>
```

Here is a sample of CSS code, is it possible that the

> rev="img1.jpg"

has a class which doesn't affect the entire `<a>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use an attribute selector:

```
a[rev]
{
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/aPrr3/

​You can expand this to select what is inside the "rev" attribute as well:

```
a[rev="img1.jpg"]
{
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/aPrr3/1/

Comment: +1 because I only understood the question after reading your answer :)